# length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property in (jquery DataTable)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I am using DataTable for displaying the list of product, the product include picture, when i return json file from my controller it gives me error

> Error during serialization or deserialization using the JSON JavaScriptSerializer. The length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property

I configure my web.config as

```
<system.web.extensions>
   <scripting>
       <webServices>
           <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="2147483644"/>
       </webServices>
   </scripting>
</system.web.extensions>
```

if i return json without picture is display properly, is there any solution to return a list of picture using json.

and my controller is

```
public JsonResult CustomServerSideSearchAction(DataTableAjaxPostModel model)
    {
        int filteredResultsCount;
        int totalResultsCount;
        var res = CustomSearchFunc(model, out filteredResultsCount, out totalResultsCount);

        var result = new List<ProductGrid>(res.Count);
        result.AddRange(res.Select(s => new ProductGrid
        {
            ProductImage = s.ProductImage,
            ProductId = s.ProductId,
            ProductName = s.ProductName,
            ProdutCode = s.ProdutCode,
            ProductPrice = s.ProductPrice,
            ProductQuantity = s.ProductQuantity,
            HeadOfficeId = s.HeadOfficeId,
            BranchOfficeId = s.BranchOfficeId
        }));

        if (totalResultsCount < model.length)
            totalResultsCount = model.length;

        return Json(new
        {
            model.draw,
            recordsTotal = totalResultsCount,
            recordsFiltered = filteredResultsCount,
            data = result
        }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

how can i resolve this problem????
thanks....

Comment: Take a look at:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151987/can-i-set-an-unlimited-length-for-maxjsonlength-in-web-config

Comment: I did that but same error, i set max length in web.config and i also set it in my controller `JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            jss.MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue;`